# openshift wso2api manager redirect error

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin

I am currently trying to setup wso2 api manager on openshift. The problem i am running into is that when i try to browse the url created by the openshift route, the application redirects me to the internally created IP address of the publisher app. However when i launch the container without openshift, the application directs me to it's intended API login page which is the Mgt console url.

I suspect this has to do with how the HAProxy embedded load balancer is behaving. I was able to hack around the configurations by changing the default ports to 443 however that created a new set of issues because changing the ports also required me hard coding container hostnames in the carbon.xml. Hardcoding settings in the configuration files prevents me from being able to scale up the containers.
Any assistance on this will be much appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of logs]

[image: Screenshot to browser redirect]